# Drawing tools in ArcGis JS not always registering clicks in IE 11

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, internet-explorer

When constructing a toolbar such as in the example given at http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/toolbar_draw/ there is a slight issue when you're trying to place to first point of any drawing tool. If you are too fast (it seems to be about 2 seconds) the click won't be registered at all. Has anyone noticed this, and found a work-around or something? There is another example here http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/graphics_add/ where this problem doesn't exist, but I haven't been able to figure out what's causing this bug.

This also goes away if you set the document mode to IE 9 and also it doesn't exist at all in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out that it has to do with the dijit themes (or some advanced CSS in general). The example I provided that works normally does not use any theming at all, and if you remove the CSS reference for the theme in the other example, it starts to work normally.

Probably not a solution for most use cases, but it might help someone to work around it.